# Is there a console command(s) that can let me switch my Asura's Star for the Black Star?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I took the Asura's Star from the quest.  But now I really regret it.  Getting soul trapped Grand Soul Gem creatures in Skyrim is a lot rarer than people.

Is there a way I can use a console commmand(s) to switch my star out?

Comment: Not really answering your question, but if you are strong enough, you can easily kill guards for Black Souls.  They respawn after some time so you have an infinite amount of readily available Grand souls.  There are also couple dungeons with people in them that have an Enchanting Table.  Fellglow Keep is one of them.  Do NOT kill the enemy in the room with the summoning circle, and the location will repopulate every 3 days or so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know about swapping, but you could always just put the Black Star in your inventory using player.additem 00063B29 1

Doing that will put the Black Star in your inventory. It should then be possible to remove Azura's Star from your inventory by selling it. Before you do that though, I'd suggest simply placing Azura's Star in a chest and taking the Black Star for a test run, to make sure it functions properly.